# Why are some subjective questions open while others aren't?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, subjective

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subjective question on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/subjective-question-on-stack-overflow)

In SO I've seen *really* subjective questions which stay open, while other ones are closed in say 3 minutes immediately without giving an explanation other than the usual boilerplate FAQ quote.

**Subjective and Open:** (few examples)

- [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)
- [Hidden Features of C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c)
- [Is 4-5 years the “Midlife Crisis” for a programming career?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685985/is-4-5-years-the-midlife-crisis-for-a-programming-career)
- [C++ Urban Myths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths)
- [Hidden Features and Dark Corners of STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596139/hidden-features-and-dark-corners-of-stl)

I've throughly enjoyed reading all of these *discussions*. But I was at a loss on why there's this difference between some questions and some others.

Comment: I guess this a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/subjective-question-on-stack-overflow. So please some one close this question. Thanks [I hope my voice is heard there in that post] :)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

> I know that we’re all programmers, so
> we love thinking of the world in
> absolute, binary terms — either fun
> questions must never be allowed, or
> fun questions must always be allowed.
> Well, I hate to be the one to break
> this to you, but the world is more …
> floating point. We will sometimes
> allow fun questions that meet the
> three broad guidelines I outlined
> above, but even then, only a limited
> amount.
>
> On Stack Overflow, contrary to popular
> opinion, we don’t hate fun. But only a
> certain amount of fun will be
> tolerated, and always with steely,
> businesslike frowns. :)

Comment: But in the blog, Jeff says about upvotes and favs count. I've seen questions getting closed in no time. Is that the time given for the stats of upvotes and favs.?

Comment: @legends: votes and favorites can still be applied to closed questions, as can reopen votes if the community feels it should be open.

Comment: "Strangest language features" was written by me.. It had 10 votes and favorites in less than 2 minutes (and then was closed in less than 3, but oh well)

Comment: er and @ State of the Union: Knowing that people can still upvote/fav a closed question made me understood. Thanks for your replies :)