# Why are so called "discussion postings" sometimes closed and sometimes not?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subjective question on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/subjective-question-on-stack-overflow)
>   [Why are some subjective questions open while others aren't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40511/why-are-some-subjective-questions-open-while-others-arent)

Some hours ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144741/whats-the-benefit-of-using-maven-in-an-android-project) which has been closed. The moderator meant that this a discussion posting. Maybe someone could explain to me what's the difference between my posting and, as example, this posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/do-i-really-need-version-control or postings with a topic "Whats a good book for....X" which are not closed? Where are the bounds?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the dates of these posts. Most of them were made at a time such questions were tolerated. You will see most of them closed and locked (and sometimes migrated or deleted to boot).

Comment: That other question is only open because it is old, and policies were different back then.

Comment: The question [Do I really need version control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/do-i-really-need-version-control) has been already removed, check the [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20100724024759/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/do-i-really-need-version-control).